# How to Class Cast Page to SearchResult in Apache Lucene

Tags: java, apache, lucene, confluence

it's my first question here.I apologize if i make any mistake or broke forum's rules
I use [confluence](http://confluence.atlassian.com/dashboard.action) and i try to write custom code for confluence search.

I have next classes

```
com.atlassian.confluence.search.v2.SearchResult;
com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page;
```

for examples when i get some pages  i try to classcast it to SearchResult to send it to velocity template

```
SearchResult sResult = (SearchResult)myPage;
```

Is there any way to add or classcast Confluence Page to SearchResult?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so - it seems `Page` is not even related to search.

Comment: if i have scope of Confluence Pages is there any way to class cast it to SearchResult or Collection<SearchResult>, or is there any best practice to work with Search Result according my question?

Comment: Bozho, Thanks for your answer. i decide this problem.